# Salvar foto via URL no banco de dados

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que necessita o *login* do Facebook. Consegui pegar os dados todos certos, porém não estou conseguindo ao salvar a foto de perfil no banco de dados. Consegui exibir a foto no `ImageView`, mas ao salvar da erro.

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   try {
   foto = bundle.getString("fotoperfil");
   if (foto != null) {
   sendFile = new File(foto);
   Log.i("sendfile", "" + sendFile);
   Log.i("fotoface", "" + foto);

   new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_perfil))
                    .execute(foto);


    }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }




   private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        Log.i("foto-face", ""+bmImage);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Log.i("foto-face","urldisplay "+urldisplay);
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            Log.i("foto-face","InputStream "+in);
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            Log.i("foto-face","mIcon11 "+mIcon11);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        Log.i("foto-face","bmImage "+bmImage);
    }
}
```

O erro ocorre no `sendFile`, porque estou passando a URL da foto. Não sei se devo fazer o *download* dela para depois salvar, se sim, podem me ajudar?

---

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: br.com.flirt, PID: 22156 java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.flirt.Utils.Util.getMd5FromFile(Util.java:162)
at br.com.flirt.EditarPerfilActivity$4$1.onResponse(EditarPerfilActivity.java:407)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: corrige a sua pergunta amigo, quando eu vi achei que voce queria so tirar uma foto de uma url e já ia responder que para isso, basta vc dar um print screen do seu browser e depois abrir o gimp e separar a linha de enedereço e pronto, tirou a foto da url, riririri

Comment: Cola o log do erro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que você está trabalhando com dados do Facebook, você não precisa salvar a foto do Facebook em sí no seu banco de dados, apenas a URL da foto ( salve como uma string).

Salvar a foto no seu banco de dados é uma péssima ideia - a menos que a sua aplicação funcione offline -, afinal, por que você salvaria a foto no seu banco de dados, consumindo espaço desnecessariamente, se o facebook já mantém ela salva no servidor deles? O que eu sugiro, como foi dito anteriormente, é que você salve apenas a URL e carregue ela dinamicamente na sua aplicação.

Para evitar erros ao carregar imagens usando AsyncTask, você poderia usar uma das diversas (e ótimas ) bibliotecas de carregamento de imagem para Android que existem, pois elas são confiáveis e possuem diversas vantagens sobre um AsyncTask que a gente implemente. Você pode usar por exemplo a biblioteca [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Veja como é fácil carregar uma imagem a partir de uma URL usando essa lib. No seu método `onCreate()`, coloque o seguinte código:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("URL-da-imagem.com")
.into(suaImageView);
```

Pronto!

Lembrando que todo carregamento é assíncrono, então não perigo de você receber um erro de **Application Not Responding**

Outras libs:

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Fresco](http://frescolib.org)

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

O facebook já faz o trabalho de hospedagem da imagem, o que recomendo é que vc salve apenas a URL da mesma, recuperando no seguinte formato:

```
mUser.getPhotoUrl().toString() + "?type=large"; //capturando a imagem no tamanho grande (getPhotoUrl() é o metodo de retorno do facebook)
```

Esse `mUser` é um `FirebaseUser`

Salve a URL da imagem. Para fazer o carregamento, use uma biblioteca para carregamento, recomendo o [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), mas tem também o [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Caso queira usar o app offline posteriormente, pelo Glide é possível salvar o cache da imagem, e ela funcionará offline.

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
  .load(url)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  .into(imageView);
```